# Pushing data from iOS to Google Cloud BigQuery

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I am new to `Google Cloud Platforms` and not quite sure with the whole architecture but what I am trying to achieve is to save some data to `Google Cloud` from an `iOS application` and do some analytics work on this data using `Google Cloud Products`, such as: `Dataproc` and `Datalab`. From what I read so far I would need to create a dataset in `Google Cloud BigQuery` and create a table in it. I have done this using the `Google Cloud Web UI` but now I want to populate the table from my `iOS app`. I can't seem to find how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The most painless route would be to **wire up Firebase Analytics and then turn on its daily log export to Big Query**, as described by Google in the walkthrough [Importing Firebase Analytics Data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query). Google maintains the entire analytic export stack for you then, seeing as they also maintain Firebase. The downside is that the analytics export happens only daily.

Alternatively, you'd be looking at using the **Big Query REST API** to upload data, as documented by Google in their [Loading Data with a POST Request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request) how-to guide. The iOS tooling for that would be your usual `NSURLSession` and `NSURLDataTask` APIs, or whatever abstraction you prefer that's built atop them.

Google does maintain [a collection of iOS-native APIs](https://developers.google.com/ios/api-docs), but unfortunately, Big Query is not included amongst the supported APIs as of May 2017. There are [native Big Query clients](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) for Go, C#, and Java, amongst others. So you could use your own API for upload to a server you control, and then use one of those client APIs serverside to implement the actual Big Query integration, if you wished.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was already looking at the last 2 options, since I need to post data on demand, not just once daily. However, I can't seem to be able to understand how this post request should look like if I want to post multiple rows to the table in `BigQuery`. Can you maybe make a simple example of how this post request would look like if I had a table with 2 columns `name` -> `STRING` and `Age` -> `INTEGER`? Thanks for your cooperation!

Comment: Google have an example in the linked documentation, look at the POST request in the section "Example: Multipart upload" [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request). Alternatively, there's a [streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll), but [Google recommend batching requests](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts) to insert ~500 records at a time (see text in "Maximum rows per request").

A question for a full, worked example using one of those APIs would make a great follow-up S.O. question.